How do I know the r_e when doing a small signal analysis for a common emitter BJT amplifier?
This video says you can get it by dividing 26mV with 1.26mA. But where did that 26mV come from? (The video does not explain the 26mV.)


It's the thermal voltage. If you want to understand it, in detail, then go here and read through the old page (it's no longer directly available). It covers the statistics involved. Otherwise, if you don't care to understand it in detail, you can just accept and use $V_T=\frac{k:T}{q}$, where $q$ is the fundamental unit of electron charge, $T$ is the absolute temperature, and $k$ is the Boltzmann constant. It's quite important when understanding PN junctions.

@periblepsis can you post this as an answer?

@VoltageSpike I guess so. But isn't all of it already captured in Andy's answer, so it would only be duplication? Mostly, I just wanted to offer Ice n Fire a link for details (if interested) -- but that link doesn't really address the question. It just allows the OP to learn something more, if desired.

The 26 mV is the thermal voltage of a diode at room temperature and equals: -
$$V_T = \dfrac{k \times T}{q}$$
Where k is Boltzmann's constant (1.380649 \$× 10^{−23}\$), T is the temperature in kelvins and q is the charge on an electron (1.6 \$× 10^{-19}\$).
So, a thermal voltage of 26 mV and, an emitter current of 1.26 mA yields an equivalent internal emitter resistance of about 21 Ω.
